# jquery javascript opening a new image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I need some assistance with this. I am trying to make an image (ad1.jpg) link url to be opened in a new tab. How would I do this? I have tried many options to make this work. I might be placing the code wrong but I have tried window.open, and many more options. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        if(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.prettyPhoto)) {
            $.prettyPhoto.open(
                "images/ad1.jpg", // Image to be opened
                "title",    // Title of the pop-up
                "desc."     // The description
            );
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.prettyPhoto.close();
            }, 10000); // autoclose after 10 seconds
        } else {
            console.log("PrettyPhoto is not defined."); // log this message
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is jquery a prerequisite?
Because if you want to click on an image and open it in a new tab you can just use `target="_blank"` like this:

```
<a href="http://link.to.your.image" target="_blank">
<img src="http://link.to.your.image" />
</a>
```

See this jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2e1eodfq/)

Comment: This would not work. The image is defined please look at the <script></script> HTML does no good in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the picture to be opened in a new tab, a simple link `<a href="images/ad1.jpg" target="_blank">` on your picture should do the work.

But if you want to open the picture in a new tab, with the borders etc... from pretty photo, I think you'll have to create a page dedicated to that, and create a link to it.

Comment: This would not work. The image is defined please look at the <script></script> HTML does no good in there.

Comment: I'm a little lost. Could you describe more specificaly what you want to do ?

Comment: yes, in the script, where the code "images/ad1.jpg" I need for when the image is clicked it opens a url in a new tab. This script has no html it sits in the footer and when the site loads the pop up works just need the image when clicked to open a new tab with a specific url

Comment: When the pop-up is shown, I guess you could add a onclick event to it ? Using jquery click function.